# Converting RTF tables into xml

Tags: c++, xml, rtf

I was given the task to convert great amount of RTF tables into XML ones (around or way more than 100.000), but I have no idea how to even start it and i cannot get help from the lead developer, because ironically he had never written a line of code.

I was thinking about c++ as I need t to be fast, but I'm open to any ideas.

What I need is some information I can start the project with or any library/program I could use for my help, thank you.

EDIT: I have XSD schemas to work with.

Comment: Google "rtf parser"

Comment: Regarding your comment about using C++, since this is a one-time job I don’t think performance is an issue here.

Comment: Take a look at this library. http://www.sautinsoft.com/convert-rtf-html-doc-docx-xls-xlsx-ppt-to-pdf-net-library/overview.php . They have an option to convert RTF to XML , but it requires .NET

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: https://github.com/paulhtremblay/rtf2xml

Comment: I was looking at the rtf2xml, but my problem was that it cannot convert pictures and they contain a good amount of them. @Galik

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after looking for a while. I can use LibreOffice to save it as html or other various forms that will keep the table as it is and also give a clear code i can pull an XSD on to make it valid also.